# Como puedo ejecutar PHP en Angular

Tags: php, angular, apache

Hasta ahora ejecuto los php para obtener datos así;

```
  this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1/TablaControl.php').subscribe(respuesta => {
            console.log(respuesta);
            this.datos = respuesta;
});
```

por supuesto tengo funcionando un php con apache en mi equipo local para interpretar el php.

¿No hay alguna manera de cuando llame a angular //localhost/4200 me interprete también el php sin depender de apache y php?

No se si me explico bien, soy algo nuevo en esto.

Comment: PHP se interpreta del lado del servidor, siempre vas a necesitar un servidor (en este caso apache) y tener el intérprete instalado

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Puedes aclarar un poco más lo que deseas hacer? Una cosa es el servidor que levanta Angular y otra muy diferente el de PHP. Aparte de que ambos están diseñados para dos partes diferentes: Angular por lo general al Frontend y PHP en el Backend. Y por lo de *novato* no te preocupes, todos somos *novatos* en algún momento. Saludos

Comment: Desconozco si el servidor que levanta angular en 4200 interpreta php, pero al reves seguro que podés, osea que el apache sirva las dos cosas, php y el contendio de angular.

Comment: La idea es que Angular interprete los PHP y no tener funcionando Apache llamando a su vez a php, ¿Angular no puede llamar a php con algun modulo?

Comment: Angular no puede interpretar PHP. Angular no es un intérprete, es un framework que corre sobre algún motor de Javascript. Son 2 mundos diferentes. No conozco ningún *package* en [npm](https://www.npmjs.com) que haga lo que buscas. PHP fue concebido y diseñado como un script para ser interpretado desde el lado Servidor (Backend). Angular por su parte fue diseñado para ser ejecutado en el lado Cliente (Frontend). El servidor que utiliza Angular durante el desarrollo es [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) y sólo es un [*bundler*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_bundling#Bundled_software)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Angular es un framework desarrollado unicamente para lado cliente FrontEnd, este framework recibe la información y la data por medio de APIs generadas por el BackEnd.

Te adjunto documentación sobre el qué es una API y como desarrollar una.

https://bbvaopen4u.com/es/actualidad/api-rest-que-es-y-cuales-son-sus-ventajas-en-el-desarrollo-de-proyectos

https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial